# How can I fill these vertices?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices, faces

I'm trying to fill these vertices here:

[image: Object that needs to be filled]

When I try to fill it with these vertices selected, this happens:

[image: Attempt at filling #1]

If I only fill with the 4 corner vertices, this happens:

[image: Attempt at filling #2]

How can I fill the vertices with the mesh only going up to the vertices of the circle?

Comment: Hello ! Looking at the grey shade of the faces here, you might have inverted normals that would throw off the automatic face fill. Try realculating the normal or get rid of the internal circular face which would make your object non-manifold if you filled all the faces (would become an internal face)

Comment: How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Also select the verts that you want the fill to "go up to". The fill command will only use the selected vertices, if you want the fill to include the rest of the verts of the circle, select them as well.